# Android: Using a memory buffer as a file

Tags: android, android-mediarecorder

Currently I'm recording the audio of my bike rides with a third-party app, while my app records GPS and BLE data. My app can also set markers which I use to mark points in time where I spoke a comment ("memo") into the microphone, so that I can map it to the audio recording.

This [GitHub issue](https://github.com/katspaugh/wavesurfer.js/issues/1178) which has screenshots may give you a better idea, but it doesn't show the markers.

I have started to experiment with Android's [MediaRecorder API](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder) in my app, and I think I could use it to replace the third-party app. I have tested it a bit and it works reasonably good.

Now look at the following code from the MediaRecorder documentation:

```
MediaRecorder recorder = new MediaRecorder();
 recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
 recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
 recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
 recorder.setOutputFile(PATH_NAME);
 recorder.prepare();
 recorder.start();   // Recording is now started
```

This is the line in question: `recorder.setOutputFile(PATH_NAME);`.

What I would like to do is to not record into the file at `PATH_NAME`, but into a memory buffer which must give me the ability to iterate over the data stream, byte-chunk by byte-chuck (ie. every 1024 bytes), which I then save myself into a file.

The reason I want to do this is so that I can save a certain amount of byte-chunks in parallel into a second file. This is so that when I press the "Memo"-marker button in my app, it will start to store what I speak into the microphone into a separate file, for about 10 seconds, while still recording the full audio into the main file. This way I could create an rss feed (or an email) of all the memos from the bike ride instead of having to load the entire 1h+ file and skipping to the marked parts.

The MediaRecorder API provides the following overrides:

```
void    setOutputFile(FileDescriptor fd)
void    setOutputFile(String path)
void    setOutputFile(File file)
```

Comment: Most audio content is stored in compressed form and with a header describing the content (e.g., bit rate, compression details). Arbitrary byte array chunks will be unplayable in isolation. If you save the full audio in a format that has good utility support (e.g., MP3), you can probably post-process that file to create 10-second valid extracts from your memo points (e.g., use `ffmpeg`).

Comment: @CommonsWare `Arbitrary byte array chunks will be unplayable in isolation`: it depends. For example, you can take a `mp3` file and slice it up at will and each slice is playable by itself. But thanks for pointing this out, because I was targeting `aac` and it looks like this is not possible with `aac`. That brings up a new problem for me :(

Comment: Hey mate, any progress on this issue? I'm in a similar situation, but instead of audio, I need to get the video frames while recoding to make an analysis of the image.

Comment: @NatanLotério Nope. I resorted to using `android.media.AudioRecord` to get the raw PCM data and then encode it with LAME via the NDK. I wish it would have been easier.